# Adding centered labels to bargraph.CI

Tags: r, text, graphics, label

I have been working on this issue for a little while now to no avail and I now turn to you all for some help/advice.  The overall goal is to take the pairwise comparison output groups from a Tukey HSD function and directly add them to a grouped bar chart.  I have many iterations of these comparisons so the ideal goal is to have this center automatically as I run the script - no manual positioning based on coordinates if possible.  As of now I have a working bargraph.CI script, a working ANOVA, and a working post-hov script - now I just need them all to play together nicely.  The issue I am facing is that the Tukey HSD group labels do not line up with the graphic's bars (ie. the output order does not correspond to the graphical order) and they are not centered.  See the outputs/graph produced after my sample script.  Thanks for any and all help!!

Some sample data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulpgrmv731yc2aw/CFLold.csv?dl=0

I do have the "reputation" to post an example image I what I have so far so here is one:

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5v7kgunapufk48t/Untitled.tiff?dl=0

This is what I have thus far:

```
library(sciplot)
library(agricolae)
mod.li <- aov(BA_Li ~ Year, CFL.old)
HSD.li <- HSD.test(mod.li,"Year", alpha = 0.05, group=TRUE, console=TRUE, main="Live Basal Area")

bg.li <- with(CFL.old, bargraph.CI(x.factor=Year, response=BA_Li,ylim= c(0,800),
              lc=FALSE, err.width = .03, xlab="Year of SB Outbreak", ylab = "Li (m2/ha)",
              x.leg=3.3, cex.leg=1, cex.names=1, cex.lab = 1,family = "Times",
              ci.fun=function(x) {c(mean(x) - 1.96*se(x), mean(x) + 1.96*se(x))}))
text(x=CFL.old$Year, labels=as.character(HSD.li$groups$M),cex=1,pos=3, xpd=T, family="Times")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost correct.

You should have written

```
text(x = bg.li$xvals, labels = as.character(HSD.li$groups$M), cex = 1, pos = 3, xpd = T, family = "Times")
```

Look at the return value for `bg.li`

Comment: Thanks for all the responses - they have been very helpful.  The advice on changing the text() line of the original code and adding the y=0 term fixed the automatic centering question - thanks!

Comment: I am hoping some of you may have an idea on how to answer the second portion of my question - making sure the letter values from the Tukey HSD output correspond with the correct x-axis value.  For instance, my outputs show that the 1940 term is "a" because it is the first letter ordered in the output, when in-fact that "a" should correspond to the Endemic class.  Meaning the Groups/Treatments from the Tukey HSD output do not correspond with the x-axis/groups on the barchart.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `m <- with(HSD.li,groups[order(groups$trt),])`. Then, `m$M` will have the correct order.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much - I have been trying to figure this out for much too long.  I appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked, but here's a solution using `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CFL.old, aes(x=factor(Year), y=BA_Li)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=function(y)c(ymax=mean(y)+1.96*se(y),ymin=0), geom="errorbar", width=0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", fill="grey70", color="black")+
  geom_text(data=HSD.li$groups, aes(x=sub("\\s+","",trt), y=0, label=M), vjust=-1)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-2,100), )+
  labs(x="Year of SB Outbreak", y="Li (m2/ha)") +
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Also, I appreciate the solution using ggplot, it is very helpful.